# Tools to document Core Data Models?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I'm starting a new project with a moderately complex Core Data model, and I'd like to know if there are any tools, within Xcode or external, that help document the decisions I'm taking while I shape the model.

Of course, I could just fire up a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're just referring to use with a doc generator:

you can use the functionality to copy the method/interfaces to the clipboard, paste to a text file which is not included in translations, then document it as usual. as long as it's in doxygen's (or whatever you use) search path, it will be added to the docs.

this could be useful in other scenarios, but that is a more common one.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and put it as answered when I can!

Answer (score 0):

This tool ([Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor)) may be useful...